 Calling All MoveIt 2 Enthusiasts! 
 Whether you're a developer, researcher, or just a passionate robotics enthusiast, I could really use your help! I'm on the lookout for top-notch resources to help broaden the community’s understanding and usage of MoveIt 2—the go-to framework for motion planning and robotic manipulation.
Here’s what I’m hoping to gather:

Beginner-friendly tutorials
Advanced guides on custom solvers, inverse kinematics, and integrating MoveIt 2 with real-world robot setups.
Code examples and GitHub repositories that demonstrate real-world applications and creative uses of MoveIt 2.
Perception and trajectory planning

 If you have any favorite resources—whether it’s something you found helpful, a project you’ve worked on, or even something you’ve created yourself—I’d love to hear about it!
**
